# Can not find StructureMapConfiguration object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I see a lot of examples of how to use StructureMap in a asp.net project like this:

```
StructureMapConfiguration.ForRequestedType<IResourceA>()
    .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<ResourceB>()
    .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton);
```

Yet, in my Global.asax I can not access the `StructureMapConfiguration` object even when I import the `StructureMap` namespace. What is the deal here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Verify that you've referenced the `StructureMap` assembly and that this assembly is of the correct version (using reflector or ildasm verify that it contains this class).

Comment: Trust me I've verified that it doesn't exist. I need to know how to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the new format:

i.e. in the form:

```
For<IResourceA>().Use<ResourceB>();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually figured it out too and came back to post it here but you had it already :) Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Add in `Application_Start()` of `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<IResourceA>().Use<ResourceB>());
```